# Laravel - php How to get current Id while inserting value in Database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get the current ID while inserting the value in database.Which i will use to save custom Data. How Do I do it?

I have written a query already.

```
  $currentId = Student::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get(['id']) + 1;
```

But it's showing the following Error :

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be
>   converted to int

Comment: `Student::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get(['id'])` will return you a collection and not an integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$currentId = Student::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->id + 1;
```

But on the heavy traffic website this potentially can cause problems with data integrity, so I'd user this approach:

```
$student = new Student();
....
$student->save();
$currentId = $student->id;
```

Comment: sir , can you help me to save the id as `001, 002 or 010` something like that?
or any idea.

Comment: You can save them as 1, 2, 10 in DB and modify them with accessor https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators - or you can add another column and add these IDs there if you do not want depend on the primary key

Comment: While there is empty database your first solution won't work because it will show `Trying to get not object property`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this :-

```
$insertData['name'] = 'your name';
$insertData['password'] = 'password';
..
```

etc..

```
// $insertData this will be your array which you want to insert in your db. name and password used in insertData array will be same as your table column name.. 

$lastId = Student::insertGetId($insertData);
```

It will give you last inserted id in laravel, it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this
$data = Student::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get(['id']);
$data->getId();

Comment: `Method getId does not exist.`